# How to access the image src using Jquery Selector

Tags: jquery

I have the div structure as shown below

```
<div  data-role="collapsible">
        <div class="prd-items-detials">
            <ul>
                <li class="head">
                    <form><input type="checkbox" class="checkboxclas" name="checkbox-mini-0" id="' + random_number + '" data-mini="true">
                    <label class="testtt" for="checkbox-mini-0">Somelabel</label>
                    </form>
                </li>
                <li class="prd-items-qt">
                    <div class="col">
                        <span class="prd-sm-img">
                        <img id="imagesd" type="img" height="40" width="40"  src="myimage.jpg"/>
                        <span>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col">
                        <i class="minus">
                        </i>
                        <i class="qt">1</i>
                        <i class="plus"></i>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col">
                    </div>
                    <div style="display: none;" class="price">120</div>
                    <div class="total">150</div>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
</div>
```

On click of the checkbox , i am unable to access the image src

I tried this way , but its not coming . could anybody please help ??

```
  $(document).on("click", ".checkboxclas", function (e) 
  {
      if ($(this).is(':checked')) 
      {
         var price = $(this).closest("ul").find("div.price").text();
         var image = $(this).closest('div[data-role="collapsible"]').find("imagesd").src.text();
      }
  });
```

Comment: What about $('#imagesd').attr('src') ?

Comment: @Superdrac Ya, because ID must be unique on document context

Answer (score 1):

You can use:

```
$(this).closest('li').next().find('img').attr('src');
```

or

```
$(this).closest('ul').find('img').attr('src');
```

If you have only one image in each `ul` element markup above.

Answer (score 0):

you have to use [prop()](http://api.jquery.com/prop/) or [attr()](http://api.jquery.com/attr/) to get the src of img like this:

```
var image = $(this).closest('div[data-role="collapsible"]').find("#imagesd").attr("src");
```